# Set special “shipping” price for afterpay payment

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5

can i configure in Magento a special shipping price for a payment solution like afterpay?

1. Customer gonna to make the payment
2. Customer can choose which payment he wanna pay with:
   A (paypal) No fee
   B (mastercard) Fee (2,-)
3. For B the customer needs to pay 2,- fee and choose B
4. The fee will be included the price
5. The customer makes his payment with the fee and the productprice

What i want is that customer MUST pay the fee when they choose for B.

Is it possible? So yes, how?

Comment: Add more details so community can provide you better solution. If you have tried any code, you can share that too. Thanks

Comment: Edit the question